# Run muliple DML statements in at once MySql

Tags: mysql

I want to exec some DML statements at once in SQL Dynamic query
How can I run it like a script?

```
update [table_name] 
set x = 1;
update [table_name_2] 
set y = 1 
where [where condition];
update [table_name_3] t3 
join [table_name_4] t4 on t3.id = t4.id  
set col_1 = 1, col_2 = 3;
```

I tried to run all statements at once and got the a syntax error

Comment: Dynamic sql can only handle 1 statement at a time,. Can you explain why you want this and someone may be able to suggest an alternative.

Comment: If the statements are independent like in your example, then it should be possible and safe to run them in parallel. How are you submitting the queries? Are you using a program or the mysql client? If the latter, you could try opening up multiple clients and running the query on each. If you're using a host program, then making it multi-threaded would be the normal way to do this. That would only be worth doing though if the time each query takes is large compared to the overhead of creating threads. If you're host program doesn't support threads, then multi-processes could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options you can follow.

1. Use a transaction.  I.e.

```
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
...
pstmt1.executeUpdate(); // Just a single update - update [table_name] set x=1
...
pstmt2.executeUpdate(); // 2nd update
...
pstmt3.executeUpdate(); // 3rd update
conn.commit();
```

So, if anyone of the 3 fails, it will roll back all the changes.

2. You can add updates in a batch and then run the whole batch. Try using `stmt.addBatch(String sql)` a number of times (once for each update), and then `stmt.executeBatch()` to execute all the 3 statements at once.
3. Use a stored procedure. Put those 3 statements in that stored procedure. And use CallableStatement to call that stored procedure.